# Change value of a child element that it works in IE7

Tags: jquery

I have following code:

```
<fieldset id="product-options-wrapper" class="product-options-off">
    <div style="width:93%;">
        <dl class="last">
            <dt class="Pass left" style="text-align: right; display: none;">Pass left&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" value="-" name="options[119]" class="input-text required-entry  product-custom-option" id="options_119_text" style="width:130px;">
</dt>
<dt>...more input fields </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And I want to change the value of the first input field. I already tried

```
jQuery('#product-options-wrapper dl').find("dt:first input").val(name);
```

But this isn't working in IE7 :(. Unfortunately I can't change the name and id of the input fields, **because they are dynamically. So I havn't direct access to it.**

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't call it by its ID? `$('#options_119_text')`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But unfortunately the id and the name are not always the same. They are dependent on certain products. Don't blame me, it is existing code...I didn't do that ;)

Comment: @PeterMiller, what is the common element in common between different products? `.product-custom-option` ?

Comment: "And I want to change the value of the first input field" is it always the first `input` element inside that `fieldset`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID already why not:

```
$("#options_119_text").val()
```

or

```
jQuery("#options_119_text").val()
```

Your code should work by the looks of it, is it inside of a

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

call?

Answer (score 0):

I make assumptions here:

```
jQuery('#product-options-wrapper").find('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val(name);
```

I assume it IS the first input element `.eq(0)`, that it is always a "text" type and that you have the same id on the `fieldset`.